# PHP convert array to resource

Tags: php, arrays, object, resources

For visual representation, for simplicity and of course to feed my curiosity, I'm wondering how to convert a PHP array into a valid PHP resource.

See the below example:
[image]
(example image created with dBug component available at http://dbug.ospinto.com/)

I've made 3 examples:

1. resource: this is the typical representation of a MySQL resource, visualized as a grid
2. object: a handmade create object from an array
3. array: a handmade multidimensional array

As you can see, the resource is a visual beauty, while the object and array are constructed by using multidimensional arrays, using poor numeric array indexes to bind them together :(

What I'm looking for, would probably be something like this:

```
$resource_var = (resource) $array_var;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: This seems to me it is not a PHP-related question, but rather a dbug-related question. Is your question "How to make dbug display the content of an object or an array the same way it displays the content of a resource?"

Comment: @Jocelyn I read that too quickly and thought you said "...rather a drug-related question." I don't think you would have been too far off.

Comment: Only you have a resource does not mean you will get beautiful output. Try with a resource handle of a CSV file and your dbug extension.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys! This is giving me new clues to work on. However, I really like the data to be sorted internally into the query grid (with rows and columns) but maybe I'm pushing to hard :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What I'm looking for, would probably something like this:
>
> ```
> $resource_var = (resource) $array(var)
> ```

You will never find that. A resource is an internal data-type in PHP. If (and only if) you write yourself a PHP extension and load it, you could do the following:

```
$resource = array_resource_create($array);
```

Your PHP extension then would create that resource (as the `mysql` extension for example creates its specific resource type) within that `array_resource_create` function. However, it would be useless, because there is no other function so far that could deal with that resource.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys! This is giving me new clues to work on. However, I really like the data to be sorted internally into the query grid (with rows and columns) but maybe I'm pushing to hard :)

Comment: Write your own a function for that and/or extend the `dbug` library you use. You would only need to check if it is an array and if so it contains only of arrays that have the same keys -or- objects that have the same properties. That is also a nice tutorial you will get in extending existing code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create resource. but you can use native one.

Try with curl for example.

```
function makeResourceFromArray($array) {

    $resource = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, serialize($array));

    return $resource;
}

function makeArrayFromResource($resource) {
    return unserialize(curl_getinfo($resource, CURLINFO_PRIVATE));
}

$resource = makeResourceFromArray(['name' => 'test']);

$array = makeArrayFromResource($resource);
```

Comment: That will lead to a resource of type `curl`. Not really what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

The output you show there is nothing to do with it being a `resource` as such, but the pretty-print function you're using noticing that the variable you've given it points at a database result set, and fetching and displaying the results.

What PHP means by a `resource` is that the variable doesn't actually hold data within PHP, but is a pointer or reference usable by some lower-level module of code - in this case, a DB library which can use that reference to retrieve the results of the executed query.

If you just want the pretty-print to look similar for an array with a DB-resultset-like structure, then you should simply modify the pretty-print function to do so - you don't need to do anything to the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

A resource is a special type. And **a resource is specific to a source that's external.** Therefore going backwards wouldn't be possible.

Theoretically, an interface with an instance of the resource would help manage the type - but this is just nonsense theoretical talk that is impossible in PHP.